# Show logged in user name using Node js + Express 4 + Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a Node Js + Express 4 + express-handlebars app. I am using Passport for local authentication. I want to show the logged in username on the top of the page. Right now I have to define it on each page render.

```
res.render('somePage', {
    title : 'My page',
    userName : req.user.Name,
});
```

I did some research and found a similar StackOverflow question (two year old question where he was using Express3) where the suggested solution was to use app.locals to set res.locals username variable.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals = {
        user: req.user
    };
    next();
});

{{user.Name}}
```

I tried that but it did not work for me.

How can I set the username once after login so I do not have to include it on every page render?

Answer (score 1):

try adding .user after locals

```
res.locals.user = {user: req.user};
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: and in your view file use {{user.user}}

Comment: hmmm, i think its better if you use session instead of locals.

Comment: because i think, if you use locals if you get redirected or page is refreshed. the locals will also get erased. :)

Comment: So what is the solution on this one? Can I use app.locals ?

Comment: Found the solution in this question after it was updated recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039970/global-properties-in-express-handlebars